# TypeError: expected a character buffer object (while writing dictionary keys to text file)

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, dictionary

Below code doesn't work:

```
with open("testfile.txt",'w') as fw:
    for key in a:
        fw.write(a[key])
```

Below is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
TypeError: expected a character buffer object`
```

Below code works:

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'w') as f:
    for key, value in a.items():
        f.write('%s:%s\n' % (key, value))
```

Can someone help me understand what's wrong in first block?

Comment: Can you post `a` dictionary values

Comment: a = {1:2,2:3,3:4}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message says: you can write only a character buffer object to a file. For example a `string`. However the entries in your dictionary are `int`s - which aren't character buffer objects. So you have first to convert the values to a string and than write it to a file, for example this conversion can be done via `'%d\n' % a[key]` or `'{0]\n'.format(a[key])`.

You could actually could use `'%s\n' % a[key]` and it would also work even if elements in the dictionary aren't integers. `%s` in python means that the conversion is done using the `str()` function, which is different from the usage in C, because in C `%s` means the formating of a null terminated string of characters. You could observe this in your second program and the reason I first thought the elements in your dictionary are `string`s.

Comment: That helps. Thanks much!